# How to display the multiple records in a line from single column and all the rows using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have column name called as email. In that, I have more than 100 rows. Some rows have more than 10 records with a comma(,) some have only 1 records. I have to display all the records in one line.

This is my table

[image]

I am getting output like

[image]

The output I need in one line so that I can export it.

```
$sql ="SELECT email FROM email12";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $a=$row['email'];
  $b = explode(',',$a);
     echo '<pre>'; print_r($b);echo '<pre>'; 
  }
  }
```

Comment: you need to attach the screenshot in the question. Do not put the link.

Comment: I am so sorry actually, screenshot button is not working on my keyboard

Comment: there are many tools available to get the snap of your screen. you could use any. I won't going to visit that link.

Comment: @Ravi,  Hope you can understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would iterate through exploded array:

```
$sql ="SELECT email FROM email12";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $a=$row['email'];
  $b = explode(',',$a);
  foreach($b as $email) {
     echo '<pre>'; print_r($email);echo '<pre>'; 
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the database's perspective, it's not recommended and certainly not a good practice to have data as comma separated list. You should consider [**normalizing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database. Having said that, you should follow the below procedure to achieve the desired result as of now(or for the time being).

Create an empty array(for example, `$resultArr`) before the beginning of `while` loop. In each iteration of `while` loop, [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) *email* column value and append them to `$resultArr` array. Finally, after coming out of the loop, simply perform [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) operation on the resultant array to *display all the records in one line*.

```
$sql ="SELECT email FROM email12";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $resultArr = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $resultArr[] = explode(',',$row['email']); 
    }
    echo implode(',', $resultArr);
}
```